# Access derived member references in base class constructor

Tags: c++, crtp

Assume I have a class, which stores references to the derived class member variables via a proxy class in a map. This map is populated in a function called let say `foo()`. It could look something like this:

```
 #include <map>
 #include <memory>

 class property_base
 {
 };    

 template<typename T>
 class property : public property_base
 {
 public:
    property(T& property) : property_(property)
    {
    }

 private:
     T& property_;
 };

 template<typename T>
 class base
 { 
 public:
     base()
     {
         static_cast<T*>(this)->foo();
     }

 protected:
     std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<property_base>> properties_;
 };

 class derived : public base<derived>
 {
 public:
     void foo()
     {
         properties_.emplace("member", std::unique_ptr<property_base>(new property<int>(value_)));
     }
 private:
     int value_;
 };
```

I know this is not considered a good pattern since I'm doing a bad thing - accessing the derived class member variables before their constructors have been run, but I only store the reference, so as far as I do not mess this up and start doing anything else with them this should be fine. That said, are there any cases/scenarios which I have overlooked and in which calling `foo()` which ONLY stores the references in the map would cause any errors?

Comment: This code would be so much easier if `base` had a protected constructor taking something like a `std::initializer_list<std::unique_ptr<property_base>>`.

Comment: "which stores references to the derived class member variables in a map" - you can't store references in a map.

Comment: @ChristianHackl fair point, didn't think of that:)

Comment: @François Andrieux - I can read the code. Thank you. My point was one of being precise in terminology and how you describe things. The map holds `unique_ptr`s, not references. So say that.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf This compiles for me with both gcc 7.2 and VS2015.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf both gcc and clang on coliru work fine, and I'm currently using this with VS2015 in my project.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Sorry, you're right, it would compile. But using the indeterminate `value_` member at `base` construction time is UB. So it's apparently not the real code at all.

Comment: You have one issue: you cannot cast `base` to `T` they are not related. So, you need `class base : public T`; Also, you could have a problem if a derived class has no 'foo' declared.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf so this falls under UB, even if I am only storing the reference?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf It's UB to read from an uninitialized value but not to make reference to it. Unless this is a special case I'm not seeing.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Oh dang. You're right again. That code is too convoluted for me. :( I've deleted my two very wrong comments. Just noting that I did post them, for context here.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not adding the properties in the `derived` class constructor?

Comment: Yes, I want to escape the fact of human error if someone makes a derived class, that forgets to do this. Again, of course the implementation of `foo` could also suffer from the same.